# Need to make my json results look like this with PHP $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, json

For a university assignment I need to be able to read and create data to a mysql database. the problem is when i $_GET data I encode it as json but thew problem is the json is laid out as i expected or needed. i was wondering if anyone could figure out if its a problem with how my table in database is set up or if it is a problem with my PHP code. i am using postman to insert into the URL and then changing the body to json.

Here is what i need it too look like:

```
{
      "oid": "AB123456X",
      "comments": [
          {
                "name": "Mary",
                "comment": "This is a comment"
          },
          {
                "name": "Anonymous",
                "comment": "Another comment"
          }
          ]
}
```

Here is what it currently looks like when i $_GET:

```
{
    "oid": "ABC123",
    "0": {
        "name": "Lucas",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    "1": {
        "name": "Kain",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Harry",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Will",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    "4": {
        "name": "Ana",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    "5": {
        "name": "Elanor",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    "6": {
        "name": "Amy",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    "7": {
        "name": "Will",
        "comment": "Hello"
    }
}
```

Here is my current PHP code for getting the data then showing it:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT name, comment 
                        FROM objects WHERE oid='$oid'");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $json_array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json_array, true);
```

Here is my table in my data base:

[Table Layout i have a Object id column a name column and a comment column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cldf.jpg)

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create an array to store the data in. This array needs 2 keys, `oid` and `comments`. Assign the `oid` key the value of `$oid`. The `comments` key should contain an empty array.

In your loop, simply add the `$row` variable to the `comments` key array.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT name, comment 
                        FROM objects WHERE oid='$oid'");

$json_array = [
    'oid' => $oid,
    'comments' => []
];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $json_array['comments'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json_array, true);
```